# Designing a backdrop for a projector

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resolution, dimensions

The width of the backdrop is 20 ft. It will be projected onto a wall. What size should the photoshop dimensions and the resolution be? This is not going to be a print file, it is going to be displayed digitally!

Comment: This is not for print, this is going to be displayed via a projector, I am a bit confused as to how to set the document up. Does it need to be set up as 20 ft with a low resolution like 50 ppi? or should I scale it down to something like 20 inch but at a high resolution.

Comment: Display system has resolution in pixels, it doesn't think of inches nor ppi. Display system programmer should tell how many pixels wide and how many pixels high the image must be to be shown without scaling.

Comment: Digital projectors project what you see on a computer monitor - the limiting factors are the resolution of the devices (i.e. the projector itself, and the computer ultimately). So, the size of the computer monitor (measured in pixels) is the size your image needs to be.  The DPI/PPI setting is irrelevant. If you don't know why, then read this: [The Myth of DPI](http://www.rideau-info.com/photos/mythdpi.html)

Answer (score 4):

Simple. See the specs for your projector.

If it is a FullHD (1920x1080px), make your file FullHD.

If it is only HD (1,280x720px) make your image HD.

It does not matter if the image projected is 1 ft or 20, or the distance to the wall. It does not change the fact that your projector can only project at its native resolution.